# Clear Left of <input type="submit"> tag

Tags: html, css

In this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/theoryshaw/RBLsF/6/) I'm trying to get the "Sign up Forgot your password?" to drop below "Sign in". (like Image 2 below)

The only way i can figure out how to do that is with using.

```
    form {overflow: hidden;}
```

...but don't want to do that, because i'd cut off the ends of the  tags. (as seen in Image 2 below)

Anyone have any other suggestions?

**Image 1:**

[image]

**Image 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply some padding to the div holidng the links:

```
<div class="devise_links" data-original-title="" style="padding-top:30px">
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/RBLsF/7/)**.

Comment: i can, but it's kinda hackish.  Was looking for a tighter way to doing this.  Thanks though.

Comment: Hmmm, how's it hackish? It's just padding pushing it down as you showed in your image. Is there something you need that you didn't specify?

Comment: no that works... was just looking for a reason why something like 'clear:left;' or 'display: block' doesn't push that tag down on a form.  In the end will use what you suggested.  Just trying to understand a method to the madness.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh OK. Try `<div class="devise_links" data-original-title="" style="clear:right">` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/RBLsF/8/

Comment: `display:block` just force the element to occupy all the `width` and `height` it already has. Try `width:auto` to force the element to take the total width and then it may work as like you want.

Answer (score 2):

you can add a clear to the parent element of the links like so:

.devise_links { clear:both; }

Answer (score 0):

would you mind to try to wrap your login button inside a `div` or `p` or any `block level element` and then giving a `clear:both` ?